# How to apply a checked attribute to multiple radio inputs fields

Tags: php, html

I am echoing out 2 radio  input fields in a foreach statement. I would like to have the first option checked in all the radio input fields that gets echoed out.

But for some reason it marks the radio input field "checked" all the way in the bottom. (The last one)

How can I make it so that every input field that gets echoed out will be marked checked?

Below is my code. Thank you for your help

```
//Foreach loop start here

<input type="radio"  checked="checked" name="display_type" value="radio" >Radio
 <br>
<input type="radio"  name="display_type" value="checkbox">Check Box
```

Comment: Could you please post your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

If multiple radios are marked as "checked", the browser applies it only to the last one. You have to distinct the loop iteration.
For example:

```
foreach ($someData as $index => $value) {
  ?>
  <input type="radio" <?php if ($index === 0) { ?>checked<?php } ?>...>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: Hey Barth. Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain me what do you mean by distinct it in the loop iteration?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your example..

How will I know what index will be at any given time?

Comment: Why? It is just an `if` inside. It is very basic. Maybe you will find this useful: http://www.yourwebskills.com/firstphp.php You can also google for `foreach` syntax or `conditional html with php` or something like that.

Comment: As an answer to your edit: you need to understand how `foreach` works. On the web there are millions of examples. Just try them out.

Comment: I know how to use a foreach and if statements. I am a experienced php developer.

I just don't understand you example when if you put if($index === o) when index will keep incrementing

Comment: And that is the point. Index will keep growing so your checked statement will be only printed for the first (0th) iteration. I barely know anything about your data structure, so my example is very general.